# Beginner having trouble simple homework code (C++ Visual Studio)

Tags: c++

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code! My code looks exactly like the professor's copy, but it won't run because of errors `E0109` and `C2064` on line 25 (the last `cout` statement).

Do I need to write equations for the `product` and `sqrt` variables, or does `cmath` automatically take care of this?

My problem is surely with the `pow()`/`sqrt()` functions.

The output should show:

```
Enter the base: 3
Enter the exponent: 2
3 to the 2 power equals 9.
The square root of 3 equals 1.73.

Press any key to continue
```

My full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int base;
    int exponent;
    int product;
    float sqrt;

    cout << "Enter the base: ";
    cin >> base;

    cout << "Enter the exponent: ";
    cin >> exponent;

    cout << base << " to the " << exponent << " power equals " << pow(base, exponent);
    cout << "The square root of " << base << " equals " << sqrt(base) << ".\n\n";
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: What are the errors? Very few people would be able to recount an error by its number.

Comment: you have a `float` variable called `sqrt`. That is a bad idea when you intend to use `sqrt()` function from `<cmath>`. Delete the row where you define that variable and you are ready to go

Comment: When interpreting error messages in Visual Studio take advantage of the Output tab (usually found on the bottom left of the screen when not debugging. It will provide much more information, including more detailed error messages. As an added bonus, the messages are pure text and easily copied and pasted into Stack Overflow questions verbatim. The error codes alone are not that helpful to us or you. I admit "C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments" isn't much help, but it does let you know that you are trying to call something that isn't a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You named a local variable `sqrt`, which hides the `sqrt()` function in `cmath`. When you then try to call `sqrt(base)`, the compiler has to resolve the `sqrt` name, so it first looks in the local scope and finds the `sqrt` variable, which is not a function and so cannot be called using the `()` operator.

Change the name of your variable to `squareRoot`, or anything else that is not `sqrt`.

Also, you are not really using that variable anyway, so strictly speaking it's not necessary and can be removed.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize you shouldn't define sqrt since it is already a function in cmath, makes perfect sense.

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue.

Comment: This is also another reason NOT to use `using namespace std` statements. That also masked the problem.  Had that statement not been present, you would have had to write `sqrt(base)` as `std::sqrt(base)` and then there would not have been any conflict with a local variable named `sqrt`. This is exactly why namespaces exist.

Comment: @Remy, std::you std::have std::to std::admit std::however std::that, std::provided std::you std::exercise std::due std::caution, std::it std::can std::make std::your std::code std::easier std::to std::read :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: The problem is, many people who feel the need to use `using namespace std` DON'T exercise the necessary caution.  If your code is so cluttered as to make it unreadable, you are coding it wrong to begin with.

Comment: `sqrt(n)` seems to be avialable even if you are not `using namespace std`. But indeed, calling it explicitly with `std::sqrt(n)` still solves it.